# How can I check to see if specific text is on a page using Playwright test automation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, playwright

I am working on my first test automation project using Playwright for .NET. For one of the tests I need to check for a specific bit of text on a page. I have been able to do a number of other tests but I can't seem to figure this one out. The JavaScript implementation includes "has-text" but I don't see that for .NET.

I used page.Locator("my text") but I don't know how to check if "my text" in fact exists on the page.

Comment: The documentation is pretty good at explaining assertions. Did you take a look at it? https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/test-assertions

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var myTextLocator = await Page.GetByText("my text");
await Expect(myTextLocator).ToHaveCountAsync(1);
```

Comment: That doesn't work in .NET

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var foo = await page.Locator("my text").TextContentAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ToContainTextAsync](https://var%20locator%20=%20Page.Locator(%22.title%22);%20await%20Expect(locator).ToContainTextAsync(%22substring%22);):

```
await Expect(locator).ToContainTextAsync("myText");
```

So just pick the locator in which you want to check. And if you want to check for visibility you could use the `UseInnerText` option.